# Swift: Filemanager swap names of 2 files

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager, file-management, file-manager

I made "collectionView reorder by using drag feature". I drag file and need to change its name on the disk to make reorder.

How can I swap file names for 2 files?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Obviously, use temporary file:

```
var tempFileURL: URL {
    let tmpDirURL = Filemanager.default
    let tmpFilename = UUID().uuidString
    let tmpFileURL = tmpDirURL.appendingPathComponent(tmpFilename)
    return tmpFileURL
}
```

After that just move:

```
let temp = FileManager.default.tempFileURL

try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: first, to: temp)
try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: second, to: first)
try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: temp, to: second)
```